# Simple example on column order for indexing "where" "order by" and "join"

Tags: index-tuning

Here are two large tables and a related query, currently there are no non-clustered indexes:

Table1 has 4 columns

```
ID (cluster index)
JOINCOLUMN
SELECTCOLUMN
WHERECOLUMN
ORDERCOLUMN
```

Table2 has many columns

```
ID (cluster index)
JOINCOLUMN
other columns....
```

Query:

```
SELECT TABLE1.SELECTCOLUMN
FROM TABLE1
INNER JOIN TABLE2
ON TABLE1.JOINCOLUMN = TABLE2.JOINCOLUMN
WHERE TABLES1.WHERECOLUMN = 'A' 
ORDER BY TABLES1.ORDERCOLUMN
```

I try to start tuning by adding non-clustered indexes, should I start with this:  May I combine "Index 1" with "Index 2"?

- "index 1" on table 1:  columns: WHERECOLUMN, ORDERCOLUMN, include SELECTCOLUMN.
- "index 2" on table 1:  column:  JOINCOLUMN
- "index 3" on table 2:  column:  JOINCOLUMN

Comment: [Rethinking Key Column Order](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/starting-sql/starting-sql-rethinking-key-column-order/)

Answer (score 2):

Table1:

```
(WHERECOLUMN,  -- 1st for filtering
 ORDERCOLUMN,  -- 2nd for having the index handle the ORDER BY
INCLUDE (SELECTCOLUMN, JOINCOLUMN) -- for covering; the order does not matter
```

I did *not* put `JOINCOLUMN` 1st or 2nd is because I wanted the consecutive rows in the index to match exactly the consecutive rows needed to satisfy the query.

Table2 -- for joining and, effectively, covering:

```
(JOINCOLUMN)
```

Sometimes is even better to get rid of TABLE1.ID and use this as the clustered index:

```
(WHERECOLUMN, ORDERCOLUMN)
```

Answer (score 1):

For `Table2` the index is rather obviously:

```
Table2 (JOINCOLUMN)
```

For `Table1` you should only create one index. The question is in which order.

- `WHERECOLUMN` should certainly come first. This is because the lookup on `Table1` is going to first need an exact match on `WHERECOLUMN`.
- `SELECTCOLUMN` can be an `INCLUDE` column, it doesn't need to be in the key. If it does, it should come last.
- Choosing between `JOINCOLUMN` and `ORDERCOLUMN` is more difficult:

1. If the join is a unique match (only one possible join match from `Table2`) then placing it first is better.
   Given your current query, this will only be the case if there is a single row in `Table2`.
   This means that the join column can be seeked, and the final result is already in the correct order and will not need sorting. It can even come before `WHERECOLUMN`.

```
Table1 (WHERECOLUMN, JOINCOLUMN, ORDERCOLUMN) INCLUDE (SELECTCOLUMN)
-- alternately
Table1 (JOINCOLUMN, WHERECOLUMN, ORDERCOLUMN) INCLUDE (SELECTCOLUMN)
```

2. The same applies for a non-unique join if the cardinality of the resultset is small, in which case a sort will be required but will not have a large impact. In this case you place `ORDERCOLUMN` as an `INCLUDE`

```
Table1 (WHERECOLUMN, JOINCOLUMN) INCLUDE (SELECTCOLUMN, ORDERCOLUMN)
```

3. If the cardinality of the final resultset is large then placing `ORDERCOLUMN` first is better. You can then place `JOINCOLUMN` as an `INCLUDE` also.

```
Table1 (WHERECOLUMN, ORDERCOLUMN) INCLUDE (SELECTCOLUMN, JOINCOLUMN)
```